# Запрос с предобработкой. Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit, xmlhttprequest, okhttp, dagger

Возникла следующая задача: Необходимо отправить запрос через `Retrofit` в котором body хешируется, и хеш закидывается в header запроса. 
Это создало проблему - я не могу написать запрос с параметрами, приходится сначала все параметры собирать в модельный класс - его в `JSON`, хешировать, и потом кидать модель в запрос параметром `@Body` . и эту последовательность надо выполнять перед каждым запросом с разными модельными классами.

Как можно это красиво реализовать? Думал о паттерне декоратор, но я работаю только с интерфейсом (т.к. ретрофит)

Так же использую `Dagger`. и Ретрофит получаю через `@provide`

**UPD:** Поискал еще и так понял надо смотреть в сторону интерсепторов?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете попробовать так

```
public interface UserService {
    @Headers({
        "CONTENT-TYPE: application/json",
        "X-APP-ID: 41"
    })  
    @PUT("/auth")
    Call<List<Task>> auth(@Header("X-APP-AUTH") String authCalculatedHeader);
}
```

**Update**

Или использовать Interceptor 
примерно так

```
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    client.interceptors().add(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request original = chain.request();

            // Customize the request
            Request request = original.newBuilder()
                    .header("Accept", "application/json")
                    .header("Authorization", String.valueOf(original.body().hashCode()))
                    .method(original.method(), original.body())
                    .build();

            Response response = chain.proceed(request);

            // Customize or return the response
            return response;
        }
    });

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("https://your.api.url/v2/")
            .client(client)
            .build();
```

Comment: Спасибо, с интерсептором разобрался, всё работает отлично

Answer (score 0):

В общем, дополняю ответ a.petrov т.к. возникли трудности, которые заметил со временем.

при хешировании я использовал request.body() но как оказалось, он возвращает мне не мой JSON а объект в котором есть поле utf8 и в нём лежит этот самый JSON. а хешировался весь объект, ну и это порождало ошибку при ответе от сервера.

Поэтому я дописал еще такой метод, который достаёт мне из request.body() JSON который я передавал параметром в retrofit метод.

```
private static String requestBodyToString(final RequestBody request) {
    try {
        final Buffer buffer = new Buffer();
        if (request != null)
            request.writeTo(buffer);
        else
            return "";
        return buffer.readUtf8();
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        return "did not work";
    }
}
```

В итоге интерсептор выглядел следующим образом

```
OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(chain -> {
        Request original = chain.request();
        Request request = original.newBuilder()
                .header("CONTENT-TYPE", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
                .header("HEADER_1",
                        AuthUtils.signHashRequestBody(requestBodyToString(original.body())))
                .method(original.method(), original.body())
                .build();
        return chain.proceed(request);
    }).build();
```

**Как итог, что я получил - Единую точку, где корректно подписываются все мои запросы - interceptor**  и никакого лишнего кода при каждом запросе :)